# A question about 1.0.3 in Grothendieck's EGA

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals, tensor-products

In (1.0.3), Grothendieck states that, given non-commutative rings $A$ and $B$, a homomorphism $\varphi : A \to B$, and a left ideal $\mathfrak{J}$ of $A$, the left ideal $B\mathfrak{J}$ of $B$ generated by $\varphi (\mathfrak{J})$ is also the image of the canonical homomorphism $B\otimes _A \mathfrak{J} \to B$ of left $B$-modules.  My questions are:

1: How is he tensoring two left $A$-modules?  By '$B$' in $B\otimes _A \mathfrak{J}$ does he mean $B$ given the structure of a *right* $A$-module via $b.a \triangleq b \varphi (a)$?

2: Then how is he giving this the structure of a left $B$-module?

3: What is the canonical map from $B\otimes _A \mathfrak{J}$ to $B$?  I imagine this will be obvious once it is clear what kind of modules he is actually tensoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** "Yes" to the second question. More precisely, he is regarding $B$ as a $\left(B,A\right)$-bimodule, where the left $B$-module structure is obvious (i.e., given by multiplication) and where the right $A$-module structure is the one you define.

"No" to the first question. He is tensoring a $\left(B,A\right)$-bimodule with a left $A$-module. This yields a left $B$-module. This also answers question **2**.

**3.** This is the left $B$-linear map which sends every pure tensor $b \otimes_A j$ to $b\varphi\left(j\right)$.